# Модификация алгоритма сортировки методом вставок

Tags: сортировка, pascalabc.net

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом, а точнее как реализовать модификацию алгоритма сортировки методом вставки (сортировка по **невозрастанию**) на PascalABC.NET.
Код процедуры:

```
p:=0;
s:=0;
for  i:= 2  to  n  do   
  if  a[i-1]<a[i]  then  
  begin
     inc(s);
     x:=a[i];  
     left:=1;   
     right:=i-1;  
     repeat    
        sred:=(left+right) div 2;
        if  a[sred]>x  then
        begin
           left:=sred+1
        end else
        begin
          right:=sred-1
        end;
     until  left>right;
     for j:=i-1 downto left do
        begin
          a[j+1]:=a[j];
        end;
     a[left]:=x;
     inc(p);
   end;
writeln('Присваиваний:',p);
writeln('Сравнений:',s);
```

Comment: Вы сами попробовали реализовать алгоритм? Если пробовали, и что-то не получилось, разметите код в вопросе, мы поможем. Если даже не пробовали, то здесь не решают задачи за других.

Comment: @andreycha да я вот только что написал процедуру. Вы не могли бы, пожалуйста, проверить, верен ли он. Мне также необходимо посчитать количество присваиваний и сравнений. Вот я привожу процедуру сортировки:

Comment: p:=0;
    s:=0;
    for  i:= 2  to  n  do   
      if  a[i-1]<a[i]  then  
      begin
         inc(s);
         x:=a[i];  
         left:=1;   
         right:=i-1;  
         repeat    
            sred:=(left+right) div 2;
            if  a[sred]>x  then
            begin
               left:=sred+1
            end else
            begin
              right:=sred-1
            end;
         until  left>right;
         for j:=i-1 downto left do
            begin
              a[j+1]:=a[j];
            end;
         a[left]:=x;
         inc(p);
       end;

Comment: Чтобы разместить код в вопросе, нажмите "править", затем вставьте код, выделите его и нажмите на кнопку с фигурными скобками: {}.

Comment: @andreycha все - код всатвлен

Comment: А в чём собственно вопрос? Не работает приведённый код, надо его как-то модифицировать? Просто мало кто будет пытаться его запустить и разбираться, что не так, а значит мало шансов, что вам ответят. Напишите подробно, что вы хотите получить, что сделали, что не получилось.